# Make R code as Excecutale

Tags: r, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, azure-web-app-service

I want to make my R code as executable so that I can integrate it with my Azure Web job and schedule it. I am using R Studio as well as Visual studio as editor. If any one know how can I make R code as executable.....? Plz help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking about compiling to make a stand-alone executable? The closest I can think of is Dirk's [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html), though it's a far cry from "make a simple executable".

Comment: A .bat file may be of use (azure indicates Windows to me).  Here's  a blog post I've done about scheduling an R task via the scheduler and a .bat file. https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2015/02/11/scheduling-r-tasks-via-windows-task-scheduler/

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new file extension and associate it with the RScriptExecutable file type.

First, change your file from .R to .Rexec (or whatever you feel like). Then from the windows command line, enter `ASSOC .Rexec=RScriptExecutable` and then `FTYPE RScriptExecutable=C:\Program Files\R-3.1.2\bin\x64\Rscript.exe %1 %*` (change to your actual path).

You should then be able to run the R script by double clicking on the .Rexec file. For more details see: https://www.r-bloggers.com/making-r-files-executable-under-windows/